# UICollectionView - dequeReusableCell return nil

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios9

I have 3 custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout layouts, and i need to change them dynamically on user inputs.

Sometimes, when i move from a layout B to layout A, inside the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: when i dequeue a cell to draw with the standard method, it returns a nil cell, which leads to a crash.

Here's how i get the cell:

```
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellClass forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The cell class is already registered. Strangely, it works when i move from layout C to A, but not from B to A.

Layout B and C use the very same classes (they just draw the content with different size/position).

This is the error i get when trying to dequeue the cell:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have u written return cell;  ?

Comment: Provide code for datasource, error seem of kind array out of bound.

Comment: yes, cell returned. but crash happens before the return anyway, right on the dequeue call.
The data source is correctly created and populated, and in fact the crash is not on the data source array.